# postgis reformat string coordinates into format for st_PointFromText()

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a single column `loc_coords` in postgresql table with combined latitude, longitude data. The data in that column looks like this:

```
(34.0539, -118.463)
```

In order to use the `Postgis` function `ST_PointFromText()` I have to reformat this text to remove the comma and parens, meaning:

```
34.0539 -118.463
```

I have been trying to find a way to do these replacements in one shot, but keep getting errors. Here is what I have been trying to do in SQL:

```
WITH comma_repl as (
SELECT replace(loc_coords,',', '') FROM t_active_bus),
rparen as (
SELECT replace(loc_coords, '(','') FROM comma_repl),
lparen as (
SELECT replace(loc_coords, ')', '') FROM rparen)

UPDATE t_active_bus
SET st_loc = st_pointfromtext('POINT(||lparen||)',4326);
```

But I keep getting an error that the `loc_coords` does not exit. I imagine the error is about `loc_coords` not existing in one of the subqueries for `rparen` and `lparen`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this even a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to create a function to achieve this?

```
create or replace function process_coords() returns text as $$
begin;
return replace(replace(replace($1,'(',''),')',''),',','');
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


UPDATE t_active_bus
SET st_loc = st_pointfromtext('POINT(' || process_coords(loc_coords) || ')',4326);
```